# Remove array of date using another array of date

Tags: javascript, angularjs, arrays, date, datepicker

I'm using [MultipleDatePicker](https://github.com/arca-computing/MultipleDatePicker) to select multiple date in year. I add a checkbox that when checked it will select all sunday in calendar.

I have a problem when unchecked it. It doesn't remove all selected sunday in calendar. I have compared by using `getTime()` as shown in the code below:

```
var selected = $scope.selectedDates;

for (var i = 0; i < $scope.selectedDates.length; i++) {
    var date1 = new Date(selected[i]).getTime();
    console.log('date1[' + i + '] = ' + date1 + ' ' + moment($scope.selectedDates[i], 'MM-DD-YYYY'));
    for (var j = 0; j < sundays.length; j++) {
        var date2 = new Date(sundays[j]).getTime();
        console.log('date2[' + j + '] = ' + date2 + ' ' + moment(sundays[j], 'MM-DD-YYYY'));
        if (date1 === date2) {
            selected.splice(i, 1);
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Some are the same and some are not. What's wrong with the code?

[Here is the plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/4C9B3LVr7z2C3GTCLd2h?p=preview) to show the problem.

Comment: while your problem got resolved already, I think you could have used [`.isSame`](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/query/is-same/) for comparing momentJS objects.. current code looks cluttered a bit.

Comment: Yeah... Thanks for suggestions and improvements

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you removed item from array and your index `i` has increased in a loop so one item got skipped. To fix this, decrease `i` after each removal:

```
    // ...
    if (date1 === date2) {
        selected.splice(i, 1);
        i--;
        break;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Little mistake, you forgot to decrement `i`, here is updated code.

```
for (var i = 0; i < $scope.selectedDates.length; i++) {
    var date1 = new Date(selected[i]).getTime();
    console.log('date1[' + i + '] = ' + date1 + ' ' + moment($scope.selectedDates[i], 'MM-DD-YYYY'));
    for (var j = 0; j < sundays.length; j++) {
        var date2 = new Date(sundays[j]).getTime();
        console.log('date2[' + j + '] = ' + date2 + ' ' + moment(sundays[j], 'MM-DD-YYYY'));
        if (date1 === date2) {
            selected.splice(i, 1);
            i--;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you forgot about decrement `i`, when you do `splice`

```
 if (date1 === date2) {
    selected.splice(i, 1);
    i = i - 1;
    break;
 }
```